# What does the ^ operator do in Java?

Tags: java, operators, exponentiation

What function does the `^` (caret) operator serve in Java?

When I try this:

```
int a = 5^n;
```

...it gives me:

> for n = 5, returns 0
>   for n = 4, returns 1
>   for n = 6, returns 3

...so I guess it doesn't perform exponentiation. But what is it then?

Comment: Can you post the actual code you are using?

Comment: I'm using eclipse and this returns 11.


public class SimpleParser {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println((10^1));
  
 }
}

Comment: In Java, `^` operator is not meant for power set. You would need `Math.pow` instead. See polygenelubricant's answer.

Comment: @WizardOfOdds: agreed, this is a good question (`^` for exponentiation? That's just common sense!). OP's exploration of the Java language needs encouraging.

Comment: [Why is my power operator (^) not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4843304/995714)

Answer (score 442):

### The ^ operator in Java

`^` in Java is the exclusive-or ("xor") operator.

Let's take `5^6` as example:

```
(decimal)    (binary)
     5     =  101
     6     =  110
------------------ xor
     3     =  011
```

This the truth table for bitwise ([JLS 15.22.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1)) and logical ([JLS 15.22.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2)) xor:

```
^ | 0 1      ^ | F T
--+-----     --+-----
0 | 0 1      F | F T
1 | 1 0      T | T F
```

More simply, you can also think of xor as "this *or* that, but *not both*!".

#### See also

- [Wikipedia: exclusive-or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive-or)

---

### Exponentiation in Java

As for integer exponentiation, unfortunately Java does not have such an operator. You can use [`double Math.pow(double, double)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) (casting the result to `int` if necessary).

You can also use the traditional bit-shifting trick to compute some powers of two. That is, `(1L << k)` is two to the *k*-th power for `k=0..63`.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia: Arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift)

---

> ***Merge note***: this answer was merged from another question where the intention was to use exponentiation to convert a string `"8675309"` to `int` without using `Integer.parseInt` as a programming exercise  (`^` denotes exponentiation from now on). The OP's intention was to compute `8*10^6 + 6*10^5 + 7*10^4 + 5*10^3 + 3*10^2 + 0*10^1 + 9*10^0 = 8675309`; the next part of this answer addresses that exponentiation is not necessary for this task.

### Horner's scheme

Addressing your *specific* need, you actually don't need to compute various powers of 10. You can use what is called the [Horner's scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner_scheme), which is not only simple but also efficient.

Since you're doing this as a personal exercise, I won't give the Java code, but here's the main idea:

```
8675309 = 8*10^6 + 6*10^5 + 7*10^4 + 5*10^3 + 3*10^2 + 0*10^1 + 9*10^0
        = (((((8*10 + 6)*10 + 7)*10 + 5)*10 + 3)*10 + 0)*10 + 9
```

It may look complicated at first, but it really isn't. You basically read the digits left to right, and you multiply your result so far by 10 before adding the next digit.

In table form:

```
step   result  digit  result*10+digit
   1   init=0      8                8
   2        8      6               86
   3       86      7              867
   4      867      5             8675
   5     8675      3            86753
   6    86753      0           867530
   7   867530      9          8675309=final
```

Comment: just to add to this answer, the function the OP is looking for is probably Math.pow(10, 1)

Answer (score 153):

As many people have already pointed out, it's the [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor) operator. Many people have also already pointed out that if you want exponentiation then you need to use [Math.pow](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29).

But I think it's also useful to note that `^` is just one of a family of operators that are collectively known as bitwise operators:

```
Operator    Name         Example     Result  Description
a & b       and          3 & 5       1       1 if both bits are 1.
a | b       or           3 | 5       7       1 if either bit is 1.
a ^ b       xor          3 ^ 5       6       1 if both bits are different.
~a          not          ~3          -4      Inverts the bits.
n << p      left shift   3 << 2      12      Shifts the bits of n left p positions. Zero bits are shifted into the low-order positions.
n >> p      right shift  5 >> 2      1       Shifts the bits of n right p positions. If n is a 2's complement signed number, the sign bit is shifted into the high-order positions.
n >>> p     right shift  -4 >>> 28   15      Shifts the bits of n right p positions. Zeros are shifted into the high-order positions.
```

From [here](http://www.leepoint.net/data/expressions/bitops.html).

These operators can come in handy when you need to read and write to integers where the individual bits should be interpreted as flags, or when a specific range of bits in an integer have a special meaning and you want to extract only those. You can do a lot of every day programming without ever needing to use these operators, but if you ever have to work with data at the bit level, a good knowledge of these operators is invaluable.

Answer (score 35):

It's bitwise XOR, Java does not have an exponentiation operator, you would have to use `Math.pow()` instead.

Answer (score 24):

XOR operator rule =>

```
0 ^ 0 = 0
1 ^ 1 = 0
0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 0 = 1
```

Binary representation of 4, 5 and 6 :

```
4 = 1 0 0 
5 = 1 0 1
6 = 1 1 0
```

now, perform XOR operation on 5 and 4:

```
     5 ^ 4 => 1  0  1   (5)
              1  0  0   (4)
            ----------
              0  0  1   => 1
```

Similarly,

```
5 ^ 5 => 1   0   1    (5)
         1   0   1    (5)
       ------------
         0   0   0   => (0)


5 ^ 6 => 1   0   1  (5)
         1   1   0  (6)
        -----------
         0   1   1  => 3
```

Answer (score 19):

It is the [`XOR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor) bitwise operator.

Answer (score 17):

Lot many people have already explained about what it is and how it can be used but apart from the obvious you can use this operator to do a lot of programming tricks like

- XORing of all the elements in a boolean array would tell you if the array has odd number of true elements
- If you have an array with all numbers repeating even number of times except one which repeats odd number of times you can find that by XORing all elements.
- Swapping values without using temporary variable
- Finding missing number in the range 1 to n
- Basic validation of data sent over the network.

Lot many such tricks can be done using bit wise operators, interesting topic to explore.

Answer (score 15):

XOR operator rule

```
0 ^ 0 = 0
1 ^ 1 = 0
0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 0 = 1
```

Bitwise operator works on bits and performs bit-by-bit operation. Assume if a = 60 and b = 13; now in binary format they will be as follows −

```
a = 0011 1100

b = 0000 1101



a^b ==> 0011 1100  (a)
        0000 1101  (b)
        -------------  XOR
        0011 0001  => 49

(a ^ b) will give 49 which is 0011 0001
```

Answer (score 14):

As others have said, it's bitwise XOR. If you want to raise a number to a given power, use [`Math.pow(a , b)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)), where `a` is a number and `b` is the power.

Answer (score 8):

AraK's link points to the definition of exclusive-or, which explains how this function works for two boolean values.

The missing piece of information is how this applies to two integers (or integer-type values). Bitwise exclusive-or is applied to pairs of corresponding binary digits in two numbers, and the results are re-assembled into an integer result.

To use your example:

- The binary representation of 5 is 0101.
- The binary representation of 4 is 0100.

A simple way to define bitwise XOR is to say the result has a 1 in every place where the two input numbers differ.

With 4 and 5, the only difference is in the last place; so

0101 ^ 0100 = 0001 (5 ^ 4 = 1) .

Answer (score 7):

To perform exponentiation, you can use Math.pow instead:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29

Answer (score 7):

It is the Bitwise xor operator in java which results 1 for different value of bit (ie 1 ^ 0 = 1) and 0 for same value of bit (ie 0 ^ 0 = 0) when a number is written in binary form.

ex :-

To use your example:

The binary representation of 5 is 0101.
The binary representation of 4 is 0100.

A simple way to define Bitwise XOR is to say the result has a 1 in every place where the two input numbers differ.

0101 ^ 0100 = 0001 (5 ^ 4 = 1) .

Answer (score 6):

As already stated by the other answer(s), it's the ["exclusive or" (XOR) operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). For more information on bit-operators in Java, see: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Answer (score 6):

That is because you are using the xor operator.

In java, or just about any other language, ^ is bitwise xor,
so of course,

10 ^ 1 = 11.
[more info about bitwise operators](http://irc.essex.ac.uk/www.iota-six.co.uk/c/e4_bitwise_operators_and_or_xor.asp)

It's interesting how Java and C# don't have a power operator.

Answer (score 3):

It is the bitwise xor operator in java which results 1 for different value (ie 1 ^ 0 = 1) and 0 for same value (ie 0 ^ 0 = 0).

Answer (score 2):

^ is binary (as in base-2) xor, not exponentiation (which is not available as a Java operator). For exponentiation, see java.lang.Math.pow().

Answer (score 2):

It is XOR operator. It is use to do bit operations on numbers. It has the behavior such that when you do a xor operation on same bits say 0 XOR 0 / 1 XOR 1 the result is 0. But if any of the bits is different then result is 1. 
So when you did 5^3 then you can look at these numbers 5, 6 in their binary forms and thus the expression becomes (101) XOR (110) which gives the result (011) whose decimal representation is 3.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the other answers, it's worth mentioning that the caret operator can also be used with boolean operands, and it returns true (if and only if) the operands are different:

```java
    System.out.println(true ^ true); // false
    System.out.println(true ^ false); // true
    System.out.println(false ^ false); // false
    System.out.println(false ^ true); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

^  =  (bitwise XOR)

Description

> Binary XOR Operator copies the bit if it is set in one operand but not both.

example

> (A ^ B) will give 49 which is 0011 0001

Comment: Without knowing the values of A or B, that example is meaningless. Other than that, it's already been said it's XOR

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at the XOR operator for `x^y`, is `x` *is not the same as* `y`, but for each bit.

Since boolean values can be represented as a single bit, the above is also transparent to boolean values.

Answer (score -1):

In other languages like Python you can do 10**2=100, try it.