# Java Operator Precedence Comparison

Tags: java

Does java have a built-in method to compare precedence of two operators?  For example, if I have a char '/' and a char '+' is there a method I can call that compares the two and returns true/false if the first is greater than the second (e.g. true)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Operator precedence the way you defined it, while common, is not a universal truth that the Java language should recognize. Therefore no, Java language itself does not have such comparison. It is of course easy to write your own:

```
int precedenceLevel(char op) {
    switch (op) {
        case '+':
        case '-':
            return 0;
        case '*':
        case '/':
            return 1;
        case '^':
            return 2;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operator unknown: " + op);
    }
}
```

Then given `char op1, op2`, just compare `precedenceLevel(op1), precedenceLevel(op2)`.

You can also use `if-else`, or ternary operators instead of `switch` if you only have very few operators. Another option would be to use an `enum Operator implements Comparable<Operator>`, but depending on what you're doing, perhaps a parsing tool like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is the better.

---

Note that the above example puts `^` at the highest precedence, implying that perhaps it's used to denote exponentiation. In fact, `^` in Java language is the exclusive-or, and it has a lower precedence than `+`.

```
    System.out.println(1+2^3);   // prints 0
    System.out.println(1+(2^3)); // prints 2
    System.out.println((1+2)^3); // prints 0
```

This just goes to show that the precedence and even semantics of these symbols are NOT universal truths.

#### See also:

- [What does the ^ operator do in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java/)

Answer (score 2):

no. your best bet is to find a 3rdparty jar that does language parsing, and see if they have methods such as that.

Answer (score 0):

You can write you own API, which performs this and Send this as a parameter and gives you the result.

Answer (score 0):

I am puzzled why you think you need this information at run-time. In every language I have ever used including algebra and English, operator precedence is predefined.

Comment: Hi- I know this is very old but I haven't logged in recently.  The question was for a school assignment involving a prefix to postfix converter.  Since the prefix expression is provided by the user, then the order of operations needed to be defined in a function so operations in the user-provided prefix could be evaluated at runtime.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Unless the operator precedence is defined by the user, it can be hardcoded into the structure of the program.