# How to implement (x pow y) in java,where x,y are double?

Tags: java

I want to calculate **x power y** and both **x,y** are **double** values. Why is java giving me a compilation error? What is the best way to do so?

I am currently using the following method:

```
x^y // attempt to calculate (x pow y)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You mentioned compilation error. In case you tried `x ^ y`, you should know that `^` in Java is _NOT_ an exponentiation operator. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java/2672217#2672217

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to implement it remains, as always:

Take the logarithm (base 10) of x; multiply it by y, and take the inverse logarithm (base 10) of the result to get x pow y.

To simply calculate it, `Math.pow(x,y);`, as has been pointed out.

Comment: Why re-implement an existing solution?

Comment: I don't know, but that was his question. (well, actually, his question title, his question was how to calculate it.)

Answer (score 8):

```
Math.pow(x, y);
```

[Read the `java.lang.Math` docs.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.pow(x,y);
```

example:

```
Math.pow(2.23, 3.45);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Math.pow(a, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [Math](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class. It has a static function pow, which accepts double values as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Double a = 3.0;
    Double b = 2.0;
    assert Math.pow(a, b) == 9.0;
```