# I keep getting this error: invalid operands to binary ^ (have 'double' and 'double')

Tags: c, binary, double, operands

Whenever I run the code my lines 52 and 61 keep giving me the same error message.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

double getinput(void);
double calcwindchillold(double v, double t);
double calcwindchillnew(double v, double t);
void printResults(double windchillold, double windchillnew);

int main(void)
{
    double v = 0;
    double t = 0;
    double windchillold = 0;
    double windchillnew = 0;

    v = getinput();
    t = getinput();
    windchillold = calcwindchillold(v,t);
    windchillnew = calcwindchillnew(v,t);
    return 0;
}
double getinput(void)
{
    double v,t;
    printf("Input the wind speed in MPH: ");
    scanf("%lf", &v);
    printf("Input the temperature in degrees Fahrenheit: ");
    scanf("%lf", &t);


    return v,t;

}

double calcwindchillold(double v, double t)
{
    double windchillold;

    windchillold = ((0.3 * v^0.5) + 0.474 - (0.02 * v) * (t - 91.4) + 91.4);
// in the line above this is the error.

    return windchillold;
}

double calcwindchillnew(double v, double t)
{
    double windchillnew;

    windchillnew = 35.74 + 0.6215*t - 35.75*(v^0.16) + 0.4275 * t * v^0.16;
// in the line above this is the second error.

    return windchillnew;
}

void printResults(double windchillold, double windchillnew)
{
    printf("The wind chill using the old formula is: %lf F\n", windchillold);
    printf("The wind chill using the new formula is: %lf F\n", windchillnew);
}
```

This has the debug system say:
error: invalid operands to binary ^ (have 'double' and 'double')

looked at other scripts that were also getting the 'double' errors and couldn't use that information to help my own.

I know its probably some simple thing that I looked over.

Comment: you can't apply `XOR` operation on `float` or `double`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my power operator (^) not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843304/why-is-my-power-operator-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

In C `^` is the eXclusive OR operator (XOR), not an exponentiation operator. You cannot XOR two floating-point values.

To exponentiate, you can use the [`pow(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/pow/) function from `math.h`.

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise operators don't work with operands of floating point type. The operands are required to have integer types.

> (C99, 6.5.11p2 Bitwise exclusive OR operator) "Each of the operands shall have integer type."

`^` is the bitwise exclusive or operator in C.

To use power operation, use the `pow` and `powf` functions declared in `math.h`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <math.h>
double pow( double base, double exp );
```

In C you cannot return multiple values, so please do a single function like this ...

```
double getinput(const char* message) {
    double retval;
    printf("%s: ", message);
    scanf("%lf", &retval);
    return retval;
}
```

Before learning about pointers and how you can master the OS, try to keep your code as simple as possible.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Another issue:

```
return v,t;
```

You can't have multiple return values in C.

You can either do this as out parameters on the call, or make separate functions.
Eg:

```
void getinput(double* v_out, double* t_out)
```