# how to print x=y^x , y=x without another variable

Tags: math

get x,y from keyboard integers
then do the following
x=y^x , y=x where x is the initial value
print the result without using another variable (only x and y allowed)

i used LOG to do it and it worked but the teacher wants a simpler way to do it(simple math).

#### Example Input:

```
X=3 Y=4
```

#### Example Output:

```
64 3
```

Comment: Do You mean `printf( "%d %d\n", pow( (int) x, (int) y ), x );`?

Comment: How about punctuation and correct capitalisation to help people make more sense out of this question?

Comment: @Jacajack: I hope not. The question is tagged as C++, not C.

Comment: @ChristianHackl You mean using `printf` instead of `std::cout`?

Comment: @Jacajack: Yes, but especially the use of C-style casts. Even if you use `printf`, `static_cast` would be better.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Oh, sorry, I didn't see your edit, it's ok now :)

Comment: Q : Write a program that receive the value of x and y from keyboard (x and y both integer) such as :
_______________
int main(){
int x ,y;
_______________
then the program should calculate the following : x=y^x , y=x where x is the initial value and print the result without using another variable (only x and y allowed)

Comment: @Jacajack
look at this

Comment: If I understand correctly, the task is to read two numbers, x and y; calculate the x:th power of y; and then print both that power and the initial value of x, all the while utilising only two variables. Is that correct?

Comment: Your teacher's skills in formulating a clear problem statement seem a bit... lacking.

Comment: yes thats how it must be 
read x/y then print x=y^x (must be stored in x)
then print y=x (save the original x in y)

Comment: @molbdnilo i hear ya :/

Comment: in C and C-like languages [`^` is the xor operator, **not power**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4843304/995714)

Comment: finished editing answer ... the problem is stated clearly enough: use integers and no more then `x,y` variables so `log,pow` are out of question ... After some thinking I approach with simple `O(n)` multiplication loop and bit manipulation to store the needed variables inside `x,y` ...

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following program for your requirement.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

int main(){
    double x = 3;
    double y = 4;

    printf("y power x is = %lf\n", pow(y,x));
    y=x;
    printf("%lf", y);
}
```

[Which will output:](http://ideone.com/XMXwZ1)

```
y power x is = 64.000000
3.000000
```

Comment: 1) indent the code. 2) In C++ it's `#include <cmath>`, not math.h. 3) `return` is not a function, do not use it like a function

Comment: it's giving me an error
and i guess it must be stored in x
not only print it
as i said i used log and it worked but the teacher wants it to be simpler

Comment: @AymanIBreak It's because Maruthi Srinivas used `printf` with `int` instead of `const char *`. Try changing it to `printf( "%d", y );`

Comment: Sorry for the error. It should be printf("%d", y)  as said by AymanIBreak.

Comment: i did so
but it didn't work
||=== Build: Debug in ayman (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\ayman\Desktop\ayman\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\ayman\Desktop\ayman\main.cpp|9|warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'double' [-Wformat]|
obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
C:\Users\ayman\Desktop\ayman\main.cpp|3|multiple definition of `main'|
obj\Debug\main.o:C:\Users\ayman\Desktop\ayman\main.cpp|3|first defined here|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: `y` is a double. The correct format specifier for a double is `%f` or `%lf`.

Answer (score -1):

**I assume**

1. `x,y` are small enough not to overflow the integer result
2. `x,y` is non negative (if negative you need to handle that too)
3. `int` is 32 bit integer

**I would use for loop ...**

- `for` is easy but you need to have iteration and result variables
- as you have forbidden adding variables you need to encode them into unused space of `x,y`
- so let limit `x,y` to 16 bits ... `<0,65535>`
- `0x0000FFFF*0x0000FFFF=0xFFFE0001`
- so you need to take care only the cases `x<=2` or `|y|<=1` all the other cases are OK
- let lower part be the `x,y` and higher `i,z`

**in source it would looks something like this (do not read if you want to code it yourself):**

```
// for (z=1,i=0      ;    i     <    x            ;i++          ) z*=y;
   for (y|=0x00010000;int(x>>16)<int(x&0x0000FFFF);x+=0x00010000) y=((int(y>>16)*int(y&0x0000FFFF))<<16)|int(y&0x0000FFFF);
// y=x;
   y=int(y&0xFFFF0000)|int(x&0x0000FFFF);
// x=z; free i
   x=int(y>>16);
// free z
   y&=0x0000FFFF;
```

**[notes]**

- if you need also negative values then you need to copy sign bit ...
- during conversion from 16->32 bit for example `if (int(y&0x00008000)) y|=0xFFFF0000;`
- and also during multiplication (xor the result sign bit by `y` sign bit)...
- or ignore it completely and compute the result sign only from `y` sign and `x` zero bit (odd/even)
- as result `z` is integer then exponent `x` should not be negative ...