# Computing distance formula as a double given integers

Tags: c++, types, casting

I am having trouble with the syntax for computing distance formula using math and its `sqrt` function. Here is the equation. I tested it out and the answers are integers.

```
sqrt(double ((x1 - 0)^2) + double ((x2 - 0)^2))
```

Comment: Hint: the ^ operator does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my power operator (^) not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843304/why-is-my-power-operator-not-working)

Comment: it's for C, but similar for C++ and all other C-based languages like Java, Javascript... Google for C++ operator first before asking here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C/C++, `^` is the operator for bitwise exclusive-or (`xor`). I assume what you are looking for is way to raise a number to the power of 2. For this you can use the `pow` function from the C standard library:

```
pow(double n, double exp);
```

Specifically,

```
sqrt(double (pow(x1 - 0, 2)) + double (pow(x2 - 0, 2))
```

Comment: aah I completely forgot about that. It's always the little things.

Comment: @dustinyourface I happens to the best of us :)

Comment: the question is about C++, not C

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc The same concept still applies since the OP seems to be using the C standard library. But I have added '/C++' to my answer to keep you happy.

Comment: yes, but the OP asked about C++ so you must answer for C++. In the original post you answer for C which is incorrect

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc If you have any problems with my answer, do feel free to provide your own alternative. Have a nice day! :)