# simple precision test getting inf output in C

Tags: c, sum, precision

Trying to test precision making a sum from 1 to a million but my output keeps coming out as inf.

```
    #include <stdio.h>



int main()
{
float x=0.0 ;
double y =0.0;
int  i;
for(i=1; i<100000; i = i+1)
{
x=(float)  x+( 1.0f/(3.0f*(float)(i*i)));
y=(double) y+ ( 1.0/(3.0*(double)(i*i)));
}
printf("Natural Order \n");
printf("Single Precision: ");
printf("%f", x);
printf("\n");
printf("Double Precision: ");
printf("%lf", y);
printf("\n");
}
```

I have changed i range many times but still getting inf as my output.

Comment: what do you want to do with i^2 ? If you meant to square i, then use i*i

Comment: I have fixed that but when i print out x and y I still get "inf"

Comment: in your code I still see a `^` symbol, is that a typo?

Comment: Yes. Im so sorry. Thank you. I realized right after I posted my edits.

Comment: If `i^2` is meant to be `i`-squared, use `i * i` instead... `^` is bitwise XOR.

Comment: The `i^2` causes a divide by zero when i is 2.

Comment: [Why is my power operator (^) not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4843304/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `i^2` means `i BITWISE-XOR 2`, not repeated multiplication.

Some values of `i^2` are zero - when `i=2` - which means you sometimes divide by zero.

Replace `(i^2)` with `(i*i)`.

Comment: Not for some value: only for i=2

Comment: @LPs - You're confusing properties of the expression with the conditions necessary to invoke those properties. The expression "some values of `i^2` are zero" is absolutely true - the condition that satisfies that expression is `i=2`. Since I've stated both the property and its condition, your criticism is pointless.

Comment: I wrote before your edit. You wrote: _Some values of i^2 are zero (odd values of i)_   Now the answer is ok.

Answer (score 3):

`i^2` is not i-squared, but a binary manipulation (xor). Use e.g. `i*i` instead. There is also the `pow` function for higher powers.

Comment: there is a `(float)` or `(double)` in front of the `1/3`, so it is not an integer division.

Comment: @mch Ok, thanks. Operator precedence is a little bit complicated in c/c++.

Answer (score 3):

What do you want is probably the following:

```
int main()
{
    float x=0.0 ;
    double y =0.0;
    int  i;

    for(i=1; i<10; i = i+1)
    {
       x= x+( 1.0f / ( 3.0f * (float)(i)*(float)(i)   ));
       y= y+(  1.0 / ( 3.0  * (double)(i)*(double)(i) ));
    }

    printf("Single Precision: ");
    printf("%f", x);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Double Precision: ");
    printf("%f", y);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

[c](/questions/tagged/c) is not like excel: `^` is not the way to pow a number/variable.

In [c](/questions/tagged/c) languace ^ is XOR [bitwise operation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm)

Your code does `i XOR i` that is `0` when `i=2`. Then the `printf` outputs inf because of the division by zero.

I did a lot of code optimization changing `LD A, 0` with `XOR A` ...Z80 talking :)

Take note that `printf` `%f` format promote passed variable to `double`.

Comment: even x that is originally a float?

Comment: If you are talking about printf promotion: yes it is.

Comment: i was testing my code with your corrections and after I set the i range past 1000 (ex.  i<10000), my output becomes "inf". Is it because i*i is too big? Wouldn't the equation be zero then?

Comment: @KassandraSandoval Yes. because of `i*i` is too much for an `int` variable. I changed posted code. In that way you could have results with larger `i` values.

Answer (score -1):

```
printf("Double Precision: ");
printf("%lf", y);               //double has %lf format specifier.
```

Actually, according to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210590/why-does-scanf-need-lf-for-doubles-when-printf-is-okay-with-just-f) `float` will automatically be promoted to `double` when needed, but depending on a compiler is a bad habit. Plus the code will not be clear to other readers.

Comment: `%lf` is used for `scanf` only. `Printf` always promote `%f` passed variable to `double` and does not care to `l` part of format.

Comment: What I said was the code will not be clear to other readers. When did I say `printf` won't promote to `double`? Where am I wrong if I said the code won't be clear?

Comment: `float` is promoted to `double` always, not when needed.