# equivalent C function, different results

Tags: c

I have a very simple C Program consisting of the following function:

```
int digit(int num)
{ 
    return num/(10*10*10);
}
```

calling digit(2345) gives back 2 - as expected.

However, if I write the function in the following way (which - in my opinion - is equivalent!!):

```
int digit2(int num)
{ 
    return num/(10^3);
}
```

and then call digit2(2345), this gives back 260 !!!
... This seems totally crazy to me !!!
I used the following parameters for compilation in each case:
    gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror

What the hell is going on here???!!!!!

Comment: `10^3` means `10 XOR 3`, which is `9`.

Comment: how do I raise a number to a power of X in C?

Comment: [Why is my power operator (^) not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843304/why-is-my-power-operator-not-working)

Answer (score 3):

`10^3` means *10 XOR 3*, not *10 to the power 3*.

To raise a number to some power, use [`pow(number, power)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) from `math.h`. Although in your case this is probably overkill as `pow` is complicated enough to raise floats to float powers, but you could just multiply the number with itself.

Comment: this is for a university assignment and I'm not allowed to import libraries so I can't use the pow function ... It's not possible to simply use 10*10*10 ... how else can I achieve to get the result of 10 to the power of x in C?
Isn't there some operator equivalent to ^in python?

Comment: @steady_progress, well, Python's power operator is `**`, not `^`: the last one still stands for XOR. In C you either multiply a number by itself, either use `pow`, either write an algorithm yourself.

Answer (score 1):

10^3 means xor - you need `pow` function - see https://linux.die.net/man/3/pow