# C issue with first calculation program

Tags: c

I am transfering from Java to C and C++ and i am having a problem with easiest tasks like this so please help me if you can:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

 void main()
 {
int a, h;
double interres;
double base;
printf("Input  a: ");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("Input  height h: ");
scanf("%d", &h);
base =(a^2 * sqrt(3))/ 4;//line 13
interres = a ^ 2 * sqrt(3);//line 14

printf("(%d^2*sqrt(3))/4=(%d^2*%f)/4=(%f*%f)/4=%f/4=%f cm",a,a,sqrt(3),a^2,sqrt(3),interres,base);

 }
```

**And I get constantly errors:**

```
error C2297: '^': illegal, right operand has type 'double' line 13
error C2297: '^': illegal, right operand has type 'double' line 14
 warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.  warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
```

Comment: See the answer to this question for the problem with `^`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843304/why-is-my-power-operator-not-working
and for the problem with scanf, try changing it to `scanf_s` as suggested.

Comment: `^` is XOR operater. So `a^2` replace with `a*a`.

Comment: `^` is the _exclusive-OR_ operator. There is no exponentiation operator in C.

Comment: i wanted to make an exponentiary operator.is there any other solution

Comment: There is a `pow` function.

Comment: thanks,i read it now.

Comment: If there was a way to see what the `^` operator is for ... There really should be something to search the internet for such things. Or maybe a book explaining the C language.

Comment: Wht did you learn about exponentation at school? Maybe there is a way to rewrite `a ** 2` to `a * a`? (`**` is **not** a C operator!)

Comment: Indentation................

Comment: @Ian - `pow()` is a poor choice for integer powers, and a very poor choice for squaring integers (it is slower, and introduces much more error).

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

In C and C++, `main` returns `int`, not `void`.  Unless your compiler documentation explicitly lists `void main()` as a valid signature, using it invokes undefined behavior.  `main` should be defined as

```
int main( void )
```

if you don't take any command line arguments, or

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
```

if you do.

Secondly, the `^` operator is the bitwise XOR operator, not an exponentiation operator; neither C nor C++ have an exponentiation operator.  You must either use the `pow` function in the standard library or roll your own.

Finally, `scanf` *can* be unsafe when reading input with either the `%s` or `%[` conversion specifiers, which you aren't doing.  Personally, I'd disable the warning as described in the error message.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

 void main()
 {
int a, h;
double interres;
double base;
printf("Input  a: ");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("Input  height h: ");
scanf("%d", &h);
base =(double)((a*a) * sqrt(3))/ 4;//line 13
interres =(double) (a *a)  * sqrt(3);//line 14

printf("(%d^2*sqrt(3))/4=(%d^2*%f)/4=(%f*%f)/4=%f/4=%f cm",a,a,sqrt(3),a*a,sqrt(3),interres,base);

 }
```

Comment: Indentation...............