# Why is 1^-1 = -2 in the C language?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Can anyone explain how x^-1 is being executed in below code. I tried but no luck. I understood how x^1 is being executed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
int a=220, b=221, c=3;
printf("a^1= %d ,, a^-1= %d \n", a^1, a^-1);
printf("b^1= %d ,, b^-1= %d \n", b^1, b^-1);
printf("c^1= %d ,, c^-1= %d \n", c^1, c^-1);
return 0;
}
/* output: a^1= 221 ,, a^-1= -221
           b^1= 220 ,, b^-1= -222
           c^1= 2   ,, c^-1= -4    */
```

Comment: What do you think `^` does?

Comment: ...'cos it's not exponentation...

Comment: Given the tags, you seem to understand what the `^` operator does. If so, you should learn about the representation of negative numbers in memory.

Comment: 1111111111111111111111111.............

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: @viki It's XOR between two integers

Comment: `x^-1` means `x xor -1` in both C & C++ : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: If by `^-1` you meant "multiplicative inverse", that was never going to work for even numbers anyway. There's no built-in operator for it in C sadly (nor most other languages)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my power operator (^) not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843304/why-is-my-power-operator-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Signed** `int`s use [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) in order to represent negative numbers.

`1` represented in int32:

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001`

`-1` represented in int32, using Two's complement:

`1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`

`XOR`ing the two results in:

`1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110`

which, for signed `int`s, is `-2`.

for unsigned ints, that would be `2^32 - 2`.

Answer (score 3):

The `^` operator is the `XOR` or [exclusive-or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) operator in C.
To make it simple, consider 8-bit signed values, using the typical [two's-complement encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The `int` type will work in the same way.

```
Decimal   Binary
      1   00000001
     -1   11111111
          -------- XOR
     -2   11111110
```

Note that the unary operator `-` has higher precedence that the `^` bitwise operator.

Comment: I especially like the terseness of this post.