# What does x ^ y do in c?

Tags: c, math

Im wondering what x ^ y does in c. I wrote a little example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int b = (3 ^ 9);
    printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

The result is 10 but i dont know how to get to that solution. Con someone explain me how to do it mathematically?

Comment: Did you try to read about in in any of the thousands of available C documents and tutorials? For easier searching try "bitwise XOR operator".

Comment: I couldn't find a proper dupe target. Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843304/why-is-my-power-operator-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `^` is the XOR or exclusive-OR operator

```
decimal  3  binary  0011
decimal  9  binary  1001
            XOR     ----
decimal 10  binary  1010
```

It operates on aligned bits individually, so the result of any pair of bits in the operands does not affect any other bits.