# How does this expression work? (c^0,c^32);

Tags: c++

```
gets(s);
for(;s[i];){
   f&=(s[i++]<'a');
}
for(i=0;s[i];){
   putchar(s[i++]^f*32);
}
```

I don't know how `s[i++]^f*32` works, I have never seen this expression before and I would like to know how it works, I know it uppercases letters if f is 1 but why is it to the 32th power and why to the 0 power it makes it lowercase

Comment: `^` isn't the power operator but the XOR operator. Please [read a book first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/995714). See [Why is my power operator (^) not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4843304/995714). See also [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714). `gets` has been removed completely from newer C and C++ standards

Comment: Not sure why that code was written in such unreadable way. I'd recommend clearing all that and rewriting the logic from scratch. As Martin Fowler said: “Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand”. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/735204/5935112) is a bunch of solutions that you can use for uppercasing the text.

Comment: What are the initial values of `f` and `i`?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I believe there's a bug in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the first comment, `^` indeed is the `XOR` operator, not the power. In top of this, there are consequences for the order of the operators, as you can see here:

```
s[i++]^f*32     // a piece of your code
=(s[i++]^f)*32  // due to the order of operators, this is the same thing.
```

What does this mean for some values, let's say `s[i++]=7` and `f=9`?

Binary, this is the situation:

```
s[i++]      = 0111
f           = 1001
s[i++]^f    = 1110
s[i++]^f*32 = 111000000
```

The result of this is 7*64=252.

As far as uppercase and lowercase are concerned, it might be interesting to know that, **in ASCII**, there is a simple relation between those, let's show you this example:

```
"A" = 65 = 1000001
"a" = 97 = 1100001

"A" XOR 32 = "a"
"a" XOR 32 = "A"
```

I believe this is what you are looking for (but I don't understand the logic behing the `f` variable).

**Edit**

Based on the comments:

Your code is wrong, it should be the following:

```
s[i++]^(f*32)
```

In case `f` is 1, this flips `s[i++]` between lowercase and uppercase. In case `f` is 0, it does nothing.

Comment: It seems `f` variable is 1 if all letters are uppercase and 0 otherwise (even if 1 letter is lowercase).

Comment: Considering `f` equal 9 may be important as a part of a general discussion of the operator, but has no meaning in this problem, as `f` can only be 0 or 1 here. (Assumed `f` is zero initially, which the presented excerpt of code doesn't show.) (It must be ONE initially, see  the comment by @i486.)

Comment: @CiaPan `f` must be 1 initially, otherwise it will always be 0.

Comment: @i486 Right, I somehow read `xor` instead of `and` there.

Comment: In case my answer solves your issue, please accept it (this is how this site works).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the magic behind it.

If you take a closer look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you'll notice that the ASCII codes of the uppercase and lowercase of the same letter differ with value 32.

So, for example the ASCII code of `A` is `65` while for `a` it's `97` and
`97 - 65 = 32`.
This means if you take any capital letter (from ASCII) and +32 to it, you'll get the lowercase of the same letter. And -32 for uppercase again.
`'A' + 32 = 0100 0001 + 0010 0000 = 0110 0001 = 'a'`

Another interesting thing, is that instead of +-32 for upper/lower casing you actually can invert the 6th bit of the character. This will have exact the same result because
`32 = 0010 0000`  (pay attention that for 32 sixth bit is 1).

And we can use XOR (`^`) operation there for that inversion.
So, `'A' ^ 32 = 'a'` and `'a' ^ 32 = 'A'`

```
A : 65 = 0100 0001  
               XOR
    32 = 0010 0000  
           |  
           v  
a : 97 = 0110 0001
```

Now let's get back to the code of the question.
Starting from the second part of the code:

```
for(i=0;s[i];){
   putchar(s[i++]^f*32);
}
```

What it does, it just iterates over the string `s` and does inversion `^32*f` based on the value of `f`.
So, if the `f` is `1` it will do inversion, if `0` then not (as `32*f = 0`).
And the value of the `f` is based on the other part of the code:

```
for(;s[i];){
   f&=(s[i++]<'a');
}
```

which determines whether all the characters of the original `s` where capital letters or not. It does that by checking if the characters are `<'a'` (as all the capital letters in ASCII are <'a').

P.S. As others also stated, the fix should be `s[i++]^(f*32)`.
The brackets are important there because of the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

P.P.S In general I'd recommend rewriting that code to make it more readable.
You might want to take a look at the other solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735204/convert-a-string-in-c-to-upper-case).

Comment: There are character encodings out there in the world that are not ASCII. This code can all be written portably with functions from the standard library, without hard-coding ASCII dependencies. In general, if you're writing "magic" code, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Totally agree! I was recommending the same in a comment of the question itself.

Comment: @RobertGaube glad that it helped. Feel free to mark it as an answer to make it easier for the others to find this question/answer :)