# Why doesn't C++ have a power operator?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

Many languages have a power operator; why doesn't C++? For example, Fortran and Python use `**` and is commonly written (in LaTeX, for example) using `^`.

Comment: `^` is the exclusive-or operator in C and C++.

Comment: Not that this is necessarily the reason, but it was already exclusive or (XOR) in C, so giving it another meaning would have broken backwards compatibility with C.

Comment: Why doesn't C++ support power (^) operator? Because.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Probably because it doesn't map to a nice instruction on a lot of platforms.

Comment: Found an answer http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/why-there-is-no-power-operator-in-java-c  (or at least a duplicate with other answers than "the operator is taken")

Comment: To the edit: Java doesn't have a power operator but python has (also **) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Nor did `/`, back when the original decision was made.

Comment: @JamesKanze I bet it did for integers?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Not on the machines I was familiar with.  Most smaller machines back then didn't have _any_ floating point support, and no hardware multiply and divide.

Comment: @JamesKanze: This is 2013, not 1969 (the year when C was invented). Arguing that the C-based family of languages should still be limited to what was available back in the stone age is archaic thinking. There is no valid reason why C++ can't have exponentiation as an operator.

Comment: @DavidHammen I was just explaining why C had `^`.  The only reason C++ hasn't added exponentiation as an operator is that the committee, after consulting with numerous experts in the field, was unable to find anyone who felt that it was necessary. Whether you spell exponentiation `x*^y` or `pow(x,y)` doesn't seem to make a difference to scientists and mathematicians.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

C++ does have a power operator—it's written `pow(x, y)`.

Originally, C was designed with system software in mind, and
there wasn't much need for a power operator.  (But it has
bitwise operators, like `&` and `|`, which are absent in a lot
of other languages.) There was some discussion of adding one
during standardization of C++, but the final consensus was more
or less:

- It couldn't be `^`, because the priority was wrong (and of
  course, having `2. ^ 8 == 256.`, but `2 ^ 8 == 10` isn't very
  pleasant either).
- It couldn't be `**`, because that would break existing
  programs (which might have something like `x**p`, with `x` an
  `int`, and `p` an `int*`).
- It could be `*^`, because this sequence isn't currently legal
  in C or C++.  But this would still require introducing an
  additional level of precedence.
- C and C++ already had enough special tokens and levels of
  precedence, and after discussions with the numerics community,
  it was concluded that there really wasn't anything wrong with
  `pow(x, y)`.

So C++ left things as they were, and this doesn't seem to have
caused any problems.

Comment: There is no ambiguity with `**`. `a ** b` doesn't make sense in the context of multiplication if `b` isn't a pointer. It does make sense in the context of exponentiation. The only rationale I can see is that the C/C++/C# community don't regard scientific programming as real programming. It's a major snub, and it's one of the key reasons Fortran programmers look down on C/C++/C# as being inferior languages for scientific programming.

Comment: @DavidHammen There are ways of resolving the ambiguity, along the lines of that used for the final `>>` in `vector<vector<T>>`.  But they involve type dependent analysis, where the types of symbols modify the way the lexer works.  If `**` were a legal token, the maximum munch rule would tokenize `a**b` as `a`, `**`, `b`, regardless.

Comment: @DavidHammen And the committee actually discussed the issue with a number of specialists in the numerics field, and they didn't seem to consider it an issue to spell the power operator `pow(x, y)`.  One of the reasons (perhaps the main reason) `*^` didn't make it is because we couldn't find anyone in the scientific community who cared.

Comment: pow() is not an operator.  Operators can be evaluated statically.  So this does not compile: enum { val = pow(2, 10) };

Answer (score 10):

For two reasons

1. The symbol `^` is reserved for bit-wise xor [operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)
2. You may use `std::pow` to achieve the same functionality.

The nice thing about C++ is that you can overload the `operator` to do whatever you like it to do!

```
template< typename T >
T operator^( T x, T y ) {
    return std::pow( x, y );
}
```

**However** take into account that when you do that, other people who know `C++` and don't know you (and I believe there are quite a few of those) might have **significant** problems understanding your code!

Comment: Yeah, but why? `^` could be power, and some other symbol could have been chosen for XOR :-)

Comment: Thanks Shai very much for this link!

Comment: @juanchopanza Fortran uses ** for power. So you are right "^ is taken" isn't really a reason not to offer power as an operator

Comment: @juanchopanza: Do you really use power of so often that it warrants an operator on its own?

Comment: @PlasmaHH - its the power of `pow`!

Comment: @PlasmaHH that has nothing to do with the reasons there is no such operator in C++. I am just pointing out that this answer doesn't justify *why* `^` was not chosen as a power operator.

Comment: @juanchopanza Originally, C was designed for more or less low level systems programming, where xor was a far more frequent operation than power.  And after that, you can't change the operators without serious backward compatibility issues.

Comment: @JamesKanze now *that's* an answer, and exactly the kind of answer I was hoping to elicit.

Comment: @PlasmaHH having used languages with power operator and languages without I find the power operator a nice feature because math writes and reads more natural with a power operator rather than having to use some power function but thats subjective. But the question was "why isn't there one?" not "why would you need one?"

Comment: As for defining an overload, as suggested: what do you make of an expression like `2^n < 100`, or `a + 2^n`.  The precedence is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's the exclusive or bitwise operator.

There are functions called "pow" that do what you want though.

Answer (score 0):

You could help yourself if you want

```
struct DoubleMock
{
    DoubleMock(double v){_v = v;}
    double _v;
};

double operator^(DoubleMock x, DoubleMock y)
{
    return pow(x._v,y._v);
}

double v = DoubleMock(2.0) ^ 2.0;
```

Comment: You must also provide all the operator set, or make it back convert implicitly to double. But the precedence will remain wrong (think to `a + 2^n`)