# What does the operator ^ stand for in java?

Tags: java

I just saw it in a code, so I tried this :

```
int i = 30;
System.out.println(i^3);
```

Result is :

> 29

What is this ? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java?rq=1

Comment: Hmmm http://tinyurl.com/av2k5s7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` its an exclusove OR operator (XOR).
Its actually bitwise sum % 2.

```
11110 (30)
00011 (3)
----------
11101 (29)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation, I mainly wanted to know why this returns 29.

Answer (score 5):

It's the Xor - [exclusive bitwise or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR).

Answer (score 3):

`^` in Java is the [XOR operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

XOR stands for a bitwise Exclusive OR. IE:

`0 XOR 0 = 0`

`0 XOR 1 = 1`

If the bit's are different (exclusive) then the output is a 1, otherwise a 0.

So following your example:

`11110 XOR
00011 =
11101 = 29`

Answer (score 3):

It is called [**Bitwise exclusive OR Operator**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html)