# Exponent Math in Java

Tags: java, math, exponent

Could anyone explain to me why

```
System.out.println(100*(1-10^(-10/10)));
```

results in the number "800" being printed out? The correct answer is 90 when you use a calculator. How would I go about doing this calculation in Java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The `^` operator does not do what you think it does. It is [bitwise-xor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java)

You need to look into the [`Math.pow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) method.

Comment: Please see the two links above. The xor explanation by @polygenelubricants is particularly in-depth.

Comment: In addition to this, the operation is actually more like: `100*((1-10)^(-10/10)))`, as the `-` operator has a higher precedence than the `^` operator.