# What does step ^= 1 mean in Java?

Tags: java

I know that `^` is the xor operator in Java. But I couldn't understand it in the following context.

```
int step = 0;
...
step ^=1;
```

Source: [Google Code Jam 2014 (Participant's answer)](http://www.go-hero.net/jam/14/name/ivan.popelyshev)

File Link : [here](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/scoreboard/do?cmd=GetSourceCode&contest=3024486&problem=5724427840913408&io_set_id=1&username=ivan.popelyshev)

Comment: step = step ^ 1 ?

Comment: It's just like all the other += etc. It performs the operation assigning its value to step.

Comment: Not sure what the question is; since you know what an xor is, why ask the question? What this will do, if this is what you ask, is always invert the least significant bit of `step`.

Comment: Why the downvote/question? What is wrong in not knowing ^= an operator in assignment operator category? It's very clear from the question. @KickButtowski solved my confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it goes under assignment operator category like

```
 += -= *= /= %= &= ^= |= <<= >>= >>>=
```

means

`^=` bitwise exclusive OR and assignment operator

`step ^=1;` as same as `step = step ^ 1;`

Answer (score 2):

`^` stands for XOR operator.

`a ^= b` is equivalent to  `a = a ^ b`

Comment: @Sashwat, thnx. Can u write me an example with real values to make it clearer please?

Comment: @nanospeck You make it sound like you know that it's the XOR operator but that you do not know what XOR does. Is this the case?

Comment: @nanospeck - Check this to get more details on XOR operator. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java. I think you already might know that XOR does the bitwise XOR between its two operands

Answer (score 1):

`step ^=1` means `step = step xor 1`. Similar to `step += 1` which gets evaluated to `step = step + 1`

So ^= is short hand xor operator.

So xor table says:

```
operand1   operand2    output
   0          0         0
   0          1         1
   1          0         1
   1          1         0
```

so if my step is 1, then 1 xor 1 would be 0.

Answer (score 1):

From Java Tutorials,

`^` 
Assume integer variable A holds 60 and variable B holds 13 then:
Binary **XOR** Operator copies the bit if it is set in one operand but not both.(A ^ B) will give 49 which is 0011 0001

In your case it is,

`step = step^1`

and in result you get `step=1`

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, `step ^=1` flips the least significant bit of `step`. This makes even numbers get 1 bigger, and odd numbers get 1 smaller.

Examples:

```
 0 --> 1
 1 --> 0
 7 --> 6
 6 --> 7
-3 --> -4
```