# Hibernate - Either field A OR B can be null but one of A or B must not be null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible in `hibernate` to model a use case in which you have two fields and either of them could be null but at least one of them must not be null? Below is the code I have at the moment but I don't like the fact that I have to set both of them to `@Column(nullable = true)`. In my case I want either the personal email address or the work address. Is there a good way to support this? Or is an alternative approach needed?

```
public class ApplicantDetails {

    //...

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private ContactDetails contactDetails;

    //...
}

public class ContactDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    /*Need at least one email address but it doesn't matter which one.*/
    @Column(nullable = true, unique = true)
    private String personalEmail;

    @Column(nullable = true, unique = true)
    private String workEmail;

    //...

}
```

Comment: look at bitwise Xor operations [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java)

Comment: @leviClouser how could it help here?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you anyway define a `CHECK` constraint in the database if your database supports some form of it:

```
CHECK (PERSONAL_EMAIL IS NOT NULL OR WORK_EMAIL IS NOT NULL)
```

Regarding the middle layer, you can simply write your own validators in services that store/update `ContactDetails` and raise the corresponding exceptions if attempts to store/update inconsistent state are made, or you can use a validation framework like [Hibernate validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/).

A quick workaround could also be to utilise entity lifecycle callback methods:

```
@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
private void validate() {
  if (personalEmail == null && workEmail == null) {
    throw new ValidationException();
  }
}
```