# Writing an equation

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to write an equation in Netbeans. 
The equation is supposed to be: `(5−x)^2 +(5−y)^2` all under a square root.

This is what I have tried:

```
public static int getScore(int x, int y){
   return ( (((5-x)^2 + (5-y)^2))^(1/2) );
```

Comment: Look into Math.pow and Math.sqrt. Also, consider using double variables and return type instead of int.

Comment: ^ performs XOR in Java. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java

Answer (score 8):

This is one of those cases where there's a specialized library function:

```
return Math.hypot(5-x, 5-y);
```

This avoids the overflow and underflow issues in computing the square root of the sum of squares directly

Comment: Do I have to import something to use this function?

Comment: No need to import anything: Math is in the `java.lang` package which is imported automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The carat ^ performs exclusive or operator in java, which is a bits thing. Don't use it for exponents.

The expression you are looking for is

```
return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(5 - x, 2) + Math.pow(5 - y, 2)));
```

Comment: Do I have to import anything for this function?

Comment: No need to import anything.