# What does "^" do in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I was using eclipse recently, trying to make a scientific calculator that performs specific functions when I tried exploring how to put a number to a specific power.  As I was exploring how to perform that function, I attempted to write the power in calculator notation (ex. 5^6).  When I did this, I received a strange answer that I was not expecting.  I tried plugging in different numbers and became even more confused.

What does the carrot (^) do in eclipse?  I would like to know its function simply for reference in case I would like to use it at another time.

Comment: assuming you are talking about Java: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1991380/1169798

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't help me very much.  I'm not sure I understand exactly what that function means.

Comment: `^` is the XOR operator in Java. Or are you using another programming language inside eclipse?

Comment: I understand that much, but what I don't know is what that means.  The explanation is a bit advanced for me.

Comment: Do some further research on it - there are a lot of simplified examples around the web, which will be easier to find now that you know what term you are looking for.