# How the ^ operator works in java? Supplemental

Tags: java, operators, xor

The similar question was asked under [What does the ^ operator do in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java)

But I think something is missing.

According to @Carl Smotricz when we have an example: 
"A simple way to define bitwise XOR is to say the result has a 1 in every place where the two input numbers differ."

So:

0101 ^ 0100 = 0001 (5 ^ 4 = 1)

And that is clear but what with:

15^4 based on that logic:
1111
100

should be 0111 but the compiler gives: 1011.

It does not work even if we use:
**Logic OR:**

false || false: **false**

false || true: **true**

true || false: **true**

true || true: **true**

Comment: `15^4 => 1111^0100 = 1011`. You appear to be equating 4, being 100, as the same thing as 1000. This is not correct, as it would have leading 0s, not trailing 0s.

Comment: Don't forget the leading zeros, and OR != XOR.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the ^ operator do in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

When applying bitwise operators to numbers that take a different amount of bits to represent, you need to add leading zeros so they "align".

In your example of 15 and 4:
15 is indeed `1111`. 4 is `100`, and you need to add leading zeroes to "pad" it up to four bits, i.e., `0100`. Now, xoring between them should give a `1` in any position where the two bits differ - `1011`, which is result you observed when trying yourself.