# Can XOR operator add or substract two operand in java?

Tags: java, operators

I want to know that the XOR operator in java can add or subtract two operand ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: If you can do this on the paper in the manner of logic rules,you can do it in all languages.

Answer (score 0):

XOR Operator in Java and almost in any languages is `^`.

Example:

```
(decimal)    (binary)
     5     =  101
     6     =  110
------------------ xor
     3     =  011
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2672217/5119030