# Trouble using the ^ operator in a calculator in netbeans (Java)

Tags: java

The error i get is "bad operand types for binary operator ^ first type: float second type: float" this error happens in case 5 of the switch x y and r are floats and n is an Int

```
  switch (n) 
         {
             case 1: r=x+y;
             case 2: r=x-y;
             case 3: r=x*y;
             case 4: r=x/y;
             case 5: r=x^y;
             default: System.out.println("Elija un numero valido");}
```

Comment: The `^` operator doesn't do what you think it does, especially with `float`s; see: [What does the ^ operator do in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991380/what-does-the-operator-do-in-java)

Comment: You perhaps mean `r = Math.pow(x, y);`.

Comment: Also, you're going to want to add `break;`s between your cases.

Answer (score -2):

`^` is only defined for [the integer-like types (`byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `char`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1) and [`boolean`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2).

In other words: exactly what the error message says. `float`s are not legal operands for the `^` operator.

And that makes sense: most people wouldn't be able to tell what the binary representation of e.g. `23.42` is. Would you? (This is actually a trick question: you cannot even represent `23.42` in binary. The closest you can get is `23.4200000000000017053025658242` whose binary representation is `01000000 00110111 01101011 10000101 00011110 10111000 01010001 11101100`.)

If the `^` operator *did* work with `float`s, it wouldn't be very obvious. E.g.

```java
2.0 ^ 3.0
```

Would be

```java
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111253692925360069154511635867
```

(I think, if I didn't make a mistake somewhere.)

Comment: Your answer makes no sense for people who think `x^y` means *exponentiation*, which seems to be the case for the questioner.

Comment: The result of `2.0 ^ 3.0` would be easier to read if you said it is `1.1125369292536007E-308`, because no one will try to count zeroes.